# Mongodb: Search in embebed documents

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have a problem with finding "all" names = y.

```
{
    "_id" : 1000013,
    "array" : [
        {
            "name" : "x"
        },
        {
            "name" : "y"
        },
        {
            "name" : "y"
        }
    ]
}
```

I tried this solution:

db.users.find( { 'array.name': 'y'})

but it returns all value from the complete array

und

```
db.users.find( { 
        'array.name': 'y'
         },{
        array: { $elemMatch: { name: 'y' } }
        } )
```

and this solution returns only one value because of $elemMatch- it returns only the first value to macht. I need the next output:

```
{
    "_id" : 1000013,
    "array" : [
        {
            "name" : "y"
        },
        {
            "name" : "y"
        }
    ]
}
```

is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.users.aggregate([{
    $match:{"array.name": "y"}
},{
    $unwind:"$array"
},{
    $match:{"array.name": "y"}
},{
    $group:{_id:"$_id", array:{$push:"$array"}}
}]);
```